# MySQL - Why are COLLATION rules ignored by LIKE operator for German ß character

Tags: mysql, collation, sql-like, diacritics

I'm running the following select statements on MySQL 5.0.88 with utf8 charset and utf8_unicode_ci collation:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE surname = 'abcß';

+----+-------------------+------+
| id | forename    | surname    |
+----+-------------------+------+
|  1 | a           | abcß       |
|  2 | b           | abcss      |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE surname LIKE 'abcß';

+----+-------------------+------+
| id | forename    | surname    |
+----+-------------------+------+
|  1 | a           | abcß       |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html the german special char ß = ss for utf8_unicode_ci, but why does it only work with the "=" operator and not with LIKE? I have a phone book application and I desperately need both things working together.

Comment: what does `show variables like '%collation%'` and `show full fields from yourtable` show? The collation has to be identical throughout.

Comment: the collation for all varchar fields of the table is set to "utf8_unicode_ci" + some int fields with no collation at all.

Comment: +1 very interesting question, love to hear the answer.

Comment: collation_connection is "utf8_unicode_ci", collation_database is "utf8_unicode_ci", collation_server is "latin1_swedish_ci". However, I thought, that the server collation is overridden by the database collation, otherwise I cant explain why it works with the "=" operator

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis,
>   thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
> +-----------------------------------------+
> | 'ä' LIKE 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
> +-----------------------------------------+
> |                                       0 |
> +-----------------------------------------+
> mysql> SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
> +--------------------------------------+
> | 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci |
> +--------------------------------------+
> |                                    1 |
> +--------------------------------------+
> ```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: Thanks Karolis. Seems I cant have both, which kind of sucks for a large phone book application with lots of special chars. Maybe the mysql FULLTEXT search could be an alternativ.