# searching arabic words that have diacritics in mysql

Tags: mysql, arabic

to make my question simple anyone knows why this query returns true

```
SELECT 'الجنة' ='الْجِنَّةِ' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

while this query returns false

```
SELECT 'الجنة' LIKE '%الْجِنَّةِ%' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
```

and how could I let the later returns true ? thanks .

Comment: See this post and the answer, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917367/mysql-why-are-collation-rules-ignored-by-like-operator-for-german-ss-character

Comment: thanks now I know why 'LIKE' operator doesn't work like '=' operator . Seems I'll have to search for another way to make my Quran search works .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here the sqlfiddle of AllInOne that I modified to make it work : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a7004/3

changed `NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE` to `BOOLEAN MODE`

and added `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci` to the db structure .

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to read up on MATCH... AGAINST... for handling "[Natural Language Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)"

I loaded the example given by mysql.com into a sql fiddle, slightly modifying it to include your arabic string and it worked as expected.

See my sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92317/1

#### UPDATE ANSWER TO INCLUDE ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS ADDED BY ASKER

(now uses BOOLEAN MODE and defines CHARSET and COLLATION)

Updated sqlfiddle by @Nyran91: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a7004/3

```
CREATE TABLE articles (
id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(200),
body TEXT,
FULLTEXT (title,body)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO articles (title,body) VALUES
('الْجِنَّةِ DCKIEW', 'DAVADV الْجِنَّةِ AVADV')


SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title,body)
AGAINST ('الجنة' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: your answer works only if you are comparing الْجِنَّةِ/الْجِنَّةِ or الجنة/الجنة. But thank you I edited your query and db sql to make it work as I want. I'll post the modified answer in a minute.

Comment: I have updated my answer to incorporate the changes you made.

Comment: Arabic also has some more problems, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748694/how-to-find-mistyping-in-arabic-and-persian-language/

Comment: But first index the field with Fulltext index and then try this,