# How to find mistyping in Arabic and Persian language?

Tags: php, string, words, persian, letters

In Persian and Arabic alphabet we have some letters that has different shape but their sounds are so close together.

These are list of those letters:

> S= س, ص, ث
>
> Gh= غ , ق
>
> T= ت,ط
>
> Z= ز , ض, ظ, ذ
>
> H= ح , ه

Many people don't know how to write words or forget the spelling and write the words wrong.

For example for the word دغدغه  it can be write in 8 ways:

> ```
> 1:  دقدغه
> 2:  دقدغح
> 3:  دقدقه
> 4:  دقدقح
> 5:  دغدغه
> 6:  دغدغح
> 7:  دغدقه
> 8:  دغدقح
> ```

How can I count how many ways a user can type a word wrong?

Is there any function for doing this in PHP?

Comment: What? You ask a question and answer it 1 second later by yourself ?

Comment: @bub Yes, you can do this, stackoverflow allow you to do this. When you are asking question, there is a checkbox that asks you if you like to answer your question?  |  This is just for helping the community. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by [Combination](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) (mathematic) that is a way of selecting items from a collection, such that (unlike permutations) the order of selection does not matter.

[image]

[image]
[Learn more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

---

**How to count number of combinations?**
[image]

As you see in image, you know the number of each letters different types,  just multiple the number of founded letters in word by the number of different types of that letter. **Here for the word what you said we have 8 results.**

And for the second question: **Yes**, there is a function for this on **[GitHub](https://github.com/m-kermani/combination)** and see the **demo** of that repository, and you can test your words there.