# MySQL find umlaute by "oe", "ae", "ue"

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to build a MySQL search query. `LIKE` would be perfectly fine, but the client wants inputs with "oe" find "ö", "ae" find "ä" and "ue" find "ü" as it's fairly common in Germany.
I tried using `REGEXP` after replacing every occurence of "oe" to `(oe|ö)` but `REGEXP` is strict and doesn't match (for instance) "é" to "e".
Is there a way to make `LIKE` match "oe|ue|ae" or maybe some other way I haven't though of?
Thanks,
thomas

Comment: Wow that was quick. Downvoted before I was finished ... :(

Comment: Probably consider investing in a search engine like Solr.

Comment: Tip: set utf8_general in mysql then `e` will find `è`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode

Comment: Not with Regexp @JustOnUnderMillions

Comment: I wouldn't use regexp. Mysql's regexp doesn't work well with multibyte characters. `The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multibyte safe and may produce unexpected results with multibyte character sets.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At [Character Sets and Collations Supported by MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html) I can only spot two German collations:

- latin1_german1_ci
- latin1_german2_ci

It seems that [latin1_german2_ci](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-we-sets.html) is the one you want, however it expects Latin1:

> `latin1_german2_ci` (phone-book) rules:
>
> - Ä = AE
> - Ö = OE
> - Ü = UE
> - ß = ss

If your table/column is not already using it, you can force such collation in the query itself, e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT _latin1'oe' collate latin1_german2_ci ='ö' AS are_equal;
+-----------+
| are_equal |
+-----------+
|         1 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your application is using Latin1 this should do the trick. Otherwise, I honestly have no idea :)

*Disclaimer: I know nothing about German. There may be another language that uses similar rules.*

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. Unfortunately our application uses UTF8 ...

Comment: @thomas If you have the chance of testing this on UTF-8 please share your experience. As I said, I don't really know MySQL handles mixed encodings.

Comment: I get an "illegal mix of collations" error. As you said, latin_german2_ci expects latin1 characters.

Comment: But this is really helpful for future projects. For now went for the ugly way of converting my search string and results via `REPLACE()`, something suggested here but later deleted (thanks to the unknown)

Comment: There's also [CONVERT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html) but I don't have experience with it.

Comment: Thanks to your `CONVERT()` comment I *almost* had it working:

`SELECT convert(_utf8'ausdruecklich' using latin1) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci = convert('ausdrücklich' using latin1) as equal` 

but then came this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917367/mysql-why-are-collation-rules-ignored-by-like-operator-for-german-%C3%9F-character

I guess I'm outta luck. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using utf8, `COLLATE utf8_german2_ci` is required.  See [*collation chart*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html)  (And, according to that chart, `german2` is the only one to satisfy your needs.)

```
mysql> SELECT "oe" = "ö" COLLATE utf8_german2_ci;
+-------------------------------------+
| "oe" = "ö" COLLATE utf8_german2_ci  |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+
```

However, It is much more efficient to declare the column(s) to be `COLLATE utf8_german2_ci` than to use that clause in comparisons.

(If you are using utf8mb4, change the spelling accordingly.)